# Checking if coordinates path cross

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I've got a bunch of coordinate points i.e ((0,1), (-1, -2)) etc.
How can I verify that two coordinate points touch?

Like displayed below(poorly), when coordinates (3,1) and (1, 2) touch/cross?

```
                |y
                |
                |- 2| (1,2)
                |   |
                |-----------| (3,1)
                |   |       |
----|---|---|---+---|---|---|----
x  -3  -2  -1   |   1   2   3
                |
                |
                |  -2
                |
                |  -3
                |
```

They cross/touch at point (1,1). I don't need a crossing point, I just need to know if they cross or not.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what exactly does it mean for two points to touch/cross ?

Comment: The points don't touch unless they are the same point. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I've edited the question, it was not well written, it's hard to draw with characters. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the coordinates of the path from (x,y) to (x,0) and (0,y) for both points, and simply check if there is an intersection between those coordinates for both points. I believe that yields the results you want.

```
# All coordinates on paths from (x,y) to (x,0) and from (x,y) to (0,y)
def path(point)
  x, y = point

  coords_x = (x >= 0 ? [*0..x] : [*x..0]).map { |c| [c, y] }
  coords_y = (y >= 0 ? [*0..y] : [*y..0]).map { |c| [x, c] }

  coords_x | coords_y
end

# p1 and p2 share a coordinate on their paths to (x,0) / (0,y) from (x,y)
def cross(p1, p2)
  ( path(p1) & path(p2) ).any?
end

p1 = [3,1]
p2 = [1,2]
cross(p1,p2) # => true

p1 = [0,0]
p2 = [0,-3]
cross(p1,p2) # => true

p1 = [-5,-5]
p2 = [-5,5]
cross(p1,p2) # => true

p1 = [-3,-3]
p2 = [3,3]
cross(p1,p2) # => false
```

Comment: thanks Daniel for your answer but if I use coordinates (3, 1) and (3, -1) I get true. And one is above and the other is below the x line so they don't cross.

Comment: Their paths touch at (3,0), I thought that had to be counted too? Niklas' algorithm would also yield true for that one.

Comment: There is no argument that a single conditional like yours is way way way more efficient here, I know :) I was just toying with it and came up with this, which is fine for small examples like the one posted.